# перечислить все дни с текущей даты

Tags: php

нужно вывести все даты начиная с текущей, и не больше 30 дней.

у меня щас так

```
$months = array('Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь');
$month_title = $months[$month-1];

$num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);

for($i=$day;$i<=$num;$i++)  {   

    $mktime=mktime(0,0,0,$month,$i,$year);

    $date = date("Y-m-d",$mktime);
    $date2 = date("Ymd",$mktime);

    $dayweek = strftime("%w", strtotime($date));
    $dayweek=str_replace("1","Понедельник",$dayweek); 
    $dayweek=str_replace("2","Вторник",$dayweek); 
    $dayweek=str_replace("3","Среда",$dayweek); 
    $dayweek=str_replace("4","Четверг",$dayweek); 
    $dayweek=str_replace("5","Пятница",$dayweek); 
    $dayweek=str_replace("6","Суббота",$dayweek); 
    $dayweek=str_replace("0","Воскресенье",$dayweek);  


?>
    <div class="tasck-list">
        <div class="dc-head <? if (''.$year.''.$month.''.$day.'' == $date2) {echo 'green';}?>" date-datetime="<?=$date;?>">
        <div class="dch-title"><?=new_time(strtotime($date));?></div>
        <div class="dch-week"><?=$dayweek;?></div>
    </div>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Отредактируйте код, поясните что вы хотите с примерами. Типа входные данные -> результат.

Comment: покажите полный код, со всеми переменными

Comment: @L.Vadim добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = date_create('2017-02-28');
for($i=0;$i<=30;$i++) {
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 days'));
}
```

[Подробности](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.add.php).

Answer (score 1):

Код:

```
 for ($i=1; $i<=30; $i++) {
        print date('Y-m-d, l', time() + 3600 * 24 * $i) . "\n";
 }
```

Результат:

```
2017-03-01, Wednesday
2017-03-02, Thursday
2017-03-03, Friday
2017-03-04, Saturday
2017-03-05, Sunday
2017-03-06, Monday
2017-03-07, Tuesday
2017-03-08, Wednesday
2017-03-09, Thursday
2017-03-10, Friday
2017-03-11, Saturday
2017-03-12, Sunday
2017-03-13, Monday
2017-03-14, Tuesday
2017-03-15, Wednesday
2017-03-16, Thursday
2017-03-17, Friday
2017-03-18, Saturday
2017-03-19, Sunday
2017-03-20, Monday
2017-03-21, Tuesday
2017-03-22, Wednesday
2017-03-23, Thursday
2017-03-24, Friday
2017-03-25, Saturday
2017-03-26, Sunday
2017-03-27, Monday
2017-03-28, Tuesday
2017-03-29, Wednesday
```

Comment: Ёшкин кот, март уже)

Comment: @vp_arth сам удивился) первая мысль была что накосячил где-то :D